# How to access properties on a custom UITableViewCell from a UiTableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to access a label property on a custom UiTableViewCell (subclassed UITableViewCell) from a UitableViewController class. For instance I have the heightForRowAtIndexPath method and I need to get access to the label.

Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // I need access to the custom UITableView Cell property here

}
```

Any tips?  Also is it even possible to declare the outlet in the uiviewcontroller and link it to the label on the custom uitableviewcell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing cell from `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, check following:

- [How to get the cell object in tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639366/how-to-get-the-cell-object-in-tableviewuitableview-tableview-heightforrowati)
- [UITableView flexible/dynamic heightForRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213024/uitableview-flexible-dynamic-heightforrowatindexpath)

---

If you need to access cell's label after it is initialized then you need to add `tag` to the label in the custom UITableViewCell class and you can access the label as following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cell"];
    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag: 1];
}
```

Comment: But how does this give you the cell in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method? That would be needed to access the label from the cell.

Comment: I have updated my answer to some links that might be helpful to access from heightForRowAtIndexPath: method

Answer (score 0):

The height calculation should be done with data from your data model, not the view. Remember, the cell was created with data from the data model.

You can't call `[tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` because this can cause infinite recursion between the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and this `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

You can try directly calling your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to get a cell but that may have undesired side effects.