# Change heightForRowAtIndexPath depending on type of UITableViewCell it uses?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'm using randomisation to create one of two different custom `UITableViewCell` types, let's call them `LCImageCell` and `LCTextCell` (one contains an image, one contains some text, and it's random which will be displayed in each row). This is laid out very basically as:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    // Determine whether the cell should contain an image or text..
    BOOL isCellAnImage;
    int randomChanceOfImageAppearing = arc4random() % 5;
    if (randomChanceOfImageAppearing == 4) isCellAnImage = YES;
    else isCellAnImage = NO;

    // If the cell is going to contain an image..
    if (isCellAnImage) {
        LCIImageCell *imageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"ImageCell"];
        if (imageCell == nil) {
            imageCell = [[LCImageCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"ImageCell"];
        }

        return imageCell;

    // Else the cell will contain text..
    } else {
        // Make and allocate the cell if necessary.
        LCTextCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
        if (customCell == nil) {
            customCell = [[LCTextCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
        }
        return customCell;
    }
}
```

I need to dynamically set the height of those with text (the `LCTextCell` instances), and that's working correctly. I'm now coming to integrate the image cells, and I'm wondering how I can let `heightForRowAtIndexPath` know whether the cell in question is an `LCImageCell` or a `LCTextCell`, so that I can only apply that height adjustment if the cell in question is an `LCTextCell`.

Can I access the cell that the height is being applied to before its height is set? Has it even been created / alloc'd / init'd by that point in time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The seemingly logical thing is to invoke `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` from within `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. However this is bad form (the latter is called well before the former for a reason) and can lead to performance issues (`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for *every* cell in the table, even the non-visible ones, each time the table is displayed).

Instead, move the cell randomization to earlier in the viewController's lifecycle. For instance, assuming you know the height for each cell type in advance (and your tableView has a single section):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
        if (arc4random() % 5 == 4) {
            [mutableArray addObject:[LCImageCell class]];
        } else {
            [mutableArray addObject:[LCImageCell class]];
        }
    }

    self.cellTypes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[self.cellTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:[LCImageCell class]]) {
        [LCImageCell height];  // class method returns static height for an image cell
    } else {
        [LCTextCell height];   // class method returns static height for a text cell
    };
}
```

If the height is dynamic, you should to [calculate and store that in advance as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213993/840428).

Comment: + 1 This is definitely the correct solution. Having randomization in cellForRow will bring only problems (e.g. when scrolling), calling for delegate method from another can bring problems, too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class (say A) for LCTextCell and another class (say B) for LCImageCell. You can define the classes to hold cell specific information (You can define a NSString instance inside class A which can be the string that gets displayed inside the LCTextCell and similarly you can have a url instance inside class B that would represent an image that is displayed inside LCImageCell). You will have to hold an array (say myArray) in your viewcontroller that would contain instances of A or B depending on what cell you would want on the specific index (row of tableview). You just have to make sure that the array has proper entries before heightForRowAtIndexPath method gets called.

You can then have

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    if([[self.myArray objectAtIndex:row] isKindOfClass:[A class]])
    {
        //LCTextCell
        return ...;
    }
        else if([[self.myArray objectAtIndex:row] isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    {
        //LCImageCell
        return ...;
    }
    return 50.0f;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *customCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([customCell isMemberOfClass:[LCImageCell class])
    {
        return ...;
    }
        else if([customCell isMemberOfClass:[LCTextCell class])
    {
        return ...;
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash somewhere in the main thread doing a `rootAllocWithZone`, caused by the `isMemberOfClass` line.

Comment: Probably it is failing because we are trying to get information from the cell while the cell doesn't already exists...
I think a better strategy would be to have a NSArray with the items that you will display in the UITableView as property, fill it randomly when the view loads and then use the set member to reload the data of your UITableView...

Tell me if you need further explanations :-)